# Mongoose only saves _id and _v

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

This is indeed a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616858/mongoose-saves-just-v-and-id) however there is no answer.

The problem is that when I save a new record with mongoose through a post request, all that's saved is something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d11590975c82f216eaa4712"), "__v" : 0 }
```

I am following this [tutorial](https://codingthesmartway.com/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-2/) so the code should work fine, but regardless here it is:

**the mongoose schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Todo = new Schema({
    todo_description: {
        type: String
    },
    todo_responsible: {
        type: String
    },
    todo_priority: {
        type: String
    },
    todo_completed: {
        type: Boolean
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', Todo);
```

**the code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const todoRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = 4000;

let Todo = require('./todo.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todos', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function() {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

todoRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(todos);
        }
    });
});

todoRoutes.route('/:id').get(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Todo.findById(id, function(err, todo) {
        res.json(todo);
    });
});

todoRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res) {
    Todo.findById(req.params.id, function(err, todo) {
        if (!todo)
            res.status(404).send("data is not found");
        else
            todo.todo_description = req.body.todo_description;
            todo.todo_responsible = req.body.todo_responsible;
            todo.todo_priority = req.body.todo_priority;
            todo.todo_completed = req.body.todo_completed;

            todo.save().then(todo => {
                res.json('Todo updated!');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
            });
    });
});

todoRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res) {
    let todo = new Todo(req.body);
    todo.save()
        .then(todo => {
            res.status(200).json({'todo': 'todo added successfully'});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new todo failed');
        });
});

app.use('/todos', todoRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});
```

**the post request:**
[image: post request]
**the get request:**
[image: get request]

To confirm here's the output in mongodb:
[image: mongodb]

Comment: I tried this example and its saving the data in all fields. Please check req.body is not empty. If req.body is empty, then it will just save _id and _v. As, no validation is applied on the fields if they are not coming in request.

Comment: I'm sure the req bosy is not empty, I tried it many times

Comment: The request you're sending is likely the problem. Add the full details for that to the question.

Comment: @LonelyDaoist When adding the data on postman, you are sending the body as "text". Select "application/json" and then hit the api. Also, you should apply validation on api entry point, if req.body is empty or null then send error in response, this way you can also check what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is that the body needs to be Json(application/json) instead of Text

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with your code

Just add this line to your todo.model.js

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', Todo);
```

Comment: sorry about that, it seems I didn't copy that line when writing the question, but no that's not the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

[image: Dashboard]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M82V9.png):

**Edit:**

I also had this problem and I fixed Content-type: application / json and it worked

Answer (score 0):

make sure you added app.use(express.json()) to your server.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `body-parser` and use:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

In the `app.js` file